# Watch route params changes, re-fetch data on change

Tags: reactjs

How can I react to route param changes? I want to re-fetch data for new params of my item.
For e.g whenever I move from `/1` to `/2` I want to fetch the data for id `2`. How can I do this using router v6?

```js
import './App.css';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Item() {
  const { id } = useParams();

    return (
      <div className="test">
       test of nested route id: { id };
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Item;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect changes with useEffect

```js
import './App.css';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect} from "react"

function Item() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    //...your function goes here
  }, [id])

    return (
      <div className="test">
       test of nested route id: { id };
      </div>
    );
  }

export default Item;
```

Comment: This may work for already-known query parameters. What if the query parameters are dynamic?  What if it contains an array? Can "useRef" be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Routing like this.

```js
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import Item from "./components/Item";

function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/main/:id" element={<Item/>}/>
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Then use params.

```js
import './App.css';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Item() {
  const { id } = useParams();

    return (
      <div className="test">
       test of nested route id: { id };
      </div>
    );
  }

export default Item;
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, I think you've miss understood my question.

Comment: I want to watch `url` change, if 1 change to 2, I want to trigger a function.